# A variable taking different values for different values in a dict

Tags: python

First off, really sorry for the title. I have this list `websites` which contains more lists. In all of those sub-lists are different website's information. Example:

```
websites=[['Amazon','www.amazon.com'],['Stackoverflow','www.stackoverflow.com']]
```

I also have a separate program that allows the user to make an account (Username and a Password). For every user, I want them to have their own `websites` list with any websites they want to add. I know that probably isn't possible but I don't want to add a new `websites` variable for every user. The code for adding information about websites (Web name,URL,username,password,email):

```
def add_website():
    clear_output(wait=False)
    website=input("Website name: ")
    clear_output(wait=False)
    url=input("URL: ")
    clear_output(wait=False)
    username=input("Username: ")
    clear_output(wait=False)
    password=input("Password: ")
    clear_output(wait=False)
    email=input("Email: ")
    clear_output(wait=False)
    dic=[website,url,username,password,email]
    websites.append(dic)
    clear_output(wait=False)
```

I essentially want every username-password combination to have a separate `websites` variable. So that every account only has the websites they added. Is there a shorter way to do this rather than just creating a huge list with every user-password combination having a different list for their websites attached?

Comment: I don't think this is the right data structure to accomplish this. Your problem would be solved fairly easily by using object-oriented programming approach. Create a `class User` and have a member attribute called `self.websites`.

Comment: "My question has a lot of components and I don't want to add a huge code because that would be impossible for people to understand." So, pretend that it doesn't. Remove required features from the program until you have the parts *that are needed to cause the problem*. Then you can show a *complete* specified input for that smaller version of the problem, along with the *exact, corresponding, complete* desired output. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to represent a single user:

```
class MyUser():

    def __init__(self, usr, pas):

        self.usr = usr
        self.pas = pas

    def add_website(self, web_name, url):

        self.web_name = web_name
        self.url = url
```

So if you had a username "user_a" with a pass "pass_a" you could create obj like:

`ua = MyUser("user_a", "pass_a")`

And another "user_b", "pass_b":

`ub = MyUser("user_b", "pass_b")`

create a list of users and add in details about websites, assuming one website per user. If you want users to be able to have more than one website, consider a Sequence or Dict type for the attributes in `MyUser`.

```
result = []  # hold objs with websites added

for i, u in enumerate([ua, ub]):

    u.add_website(*websites[i])

    result.append(u)
```

Your output is a list `result` of users with distinct credentials and websites attached to each type `MyUser`.

Comment: Take a big website like amazon for example. There must be millions of account on the website and every account has their own banking information, shipping address, etc. Using the method you just said, I would have to create enough variables to match the amount of accounts. Pretend I had a million accounts. How else would I be able to solve my problem?